# What Dart's List's "some" method is called? Method checking if at least one element passes a test

Tags: list, flutter, dart, iterable

On JavaScript arrays, there is the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

I think there must be a similar method on the Dart lists, too, but I just can't seem to find it anywhere on the internet or in the [`List` docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/List-class.html).

I got used to Dart having different names for some of the methods, so I always spend like 5 minutes until I remember that JavaScript's [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is called [`where`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/where.html), and so on. However, I can't seem to find `some`'s equivalent.

Answer (score 13):

Huh! The problem was that the equivalent of JavaScript's `some` method is a method on the [`Iterable` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable-class.html) and not on the `List`. The `List` class implements the `Iterable`, though, so I could have found it earlier, but I guess I was lost in all those method descriptions.

**Dart's equivalent of the `some` method is called: [`any`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/any.html)**:

> *`Iterable<E>`* **`bool any(bool test(E element))`**
>
> Checks whether any element of this iterable satisfies `test`.
>
> Checks every element in iteration order, and returns true if any of them make test return true, otherwise returns false.

Example usage:

```
// The list in which we want to check if there is an item that passes a certain test.
List<String> haystack = [
  // It contains some elements...
];
// Just to be explicit in this example, you don't really need it
typedef TestFunc = bool Function(String);
// The test. Just some function that takes an element and returns boolean.
TestFunc isNeedle = (String v) => v.toLowerCase().contains('needle');

bool gotNeedle = haystack.any(isNeedle);
```